# Different XIB files for iPhone 5 automatically

Tags: ios, xib

I am updating my app to support the new iPhone 5.

I was wondering if there's any sort of way that you can create a different XIB file for the iPhone 5 that will load automatically, like when images with "@2x" in the end are loaded automatically when an iPhone 4 is used, without having to make any changes to the code itself.

Thanks!

Comment: not recommended. this approach *often* decays to messy duplication.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no simple way to load correct xib for iPhone5 without extra code. However, i can suggest [this simple class](https://github.com/eagle-dan1349/EDDeviceHardware) for detecting iPhone5. In addition, there also is a category for selecting correct image for iPhone5 [here](http://www.sourcedrop.net/FY53a14b0127f). You can do the same for initWithNibName:bundle: method.

Comment: There is no way to append a string to messages like in the @2x case?

Comment: Correct spelling is "there is no simple way". Please, see the code for category I provided. I used slightly modified version for image selection and it worked nice. The same thing could be done for .xib loading